# shell /bash script - how do I execute multiple scripts at once using while

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=1;i <=10;i++))
do
  php /var/www/get.php
done
```

I have the above shell script that I'm using to execute get.php for 10 times . However it seems that the script(s) are executed one by one so I would like to know if it's possible to execute all of them at once (obviously without to type the php path command for 10 times )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run them all concurrently, you can change:

```
php /var/www/get.php
```

into:

```
php /var/www/get.php &
```

This runs the process in the background rather than the foreground. It's your responsibility to ensure that your script is *functional* when running in the background of course. You may have to watch out for resources that don't like being shared, or mingling of the outputs from the different processes.

If you also wanted to *wait* for all ten to finish as well, start with:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=1;i <=10;i++))
do
  php /var/www/get.php &
done
wait
```

Comment: does php /var/www/get.php > get.txt have the same effect(to run in the background) as php /var/www/get.php & ?

Comment: @Michael, no. That just redirects the output. It still runs in the foreground. Background means that the parent starts the child and keeps going (so they run side-by-side). Foreground means parent will wait for child to finish, which is unaffected by output redirection.

Comment: reading `man bash`, I'm kinda confused at _"If n is not given, all currently active child processes are  waited  for"_. Doesn't that mean just one `wait` is necessary? CMIIW

Comment: @pepoluan, sorry, you're right, the loop isn't needed here since `wait` will wait for them all. I must be confusing it with one of my many other languages I purport to know :-) I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=1;i <=10;i++))
do
  php /var/www/get.php &
done
```

Just add an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation :

```
seq 1 3 | while read i; do /usr/bin/php -v &; done;
```